# simplest method for Copying all objects into array

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2

I have around 250 json files which i want to copy to an array, my project is based on vuejs and webpack

here is my code below

```
import ch1 from 'assets/json/ar/ch1.json';
import ch2 from 'assets/json/ar/ch2.json';
....
....
import ch100 from 'assets/json/ar/ch100.json';
import ch101 from 'assets/json/ar/ch101.json';
import ch102 from 'assets/json/ar/ch102.json';
import ch103 from 'assets/json/ar/ch103.json';
import ch104 from 'assets/json/ar/ch104.json';
import ch105 from 'assets/json/ar/ch105.json';
import ch106 from 'assets/json/ar/ch106.json';
import ch107 from 'assets/json/ar/ch107.json';
import ch108 from 'assets/json/ar/ch108.json';
import ch109 from 'assets/json/ar/ch109.json';

.....
....
import ch250  from 'assets/json/ar/ch250.json';



var myalldata=  []
// i can  do this manually  as assigning to each index like below
// myalldata[1]=ch1 ;
// myalldata[2]=ch2 ; but its too lengthy code



//here i export all data as array
export default { 
  alldata:myalldata
}
```

**can i use for loop for copying all objects to myalldata?? how to do that**

Comment: Why do you use `import`? JSON is a data format, JSON is not meant for importing code modules. You could make an AJAX call to load one JSON, and when it's loaded, you load the next and append it to the result of the previous one. Keep doing this until all 250 files are loaded.

Comment: @Kokodoko Why AJAX? JSON files (if they are static) could be compiled using webpack, reducing network usage.

Comment: Except these are, I assume, chapter files for a book or a game or something. AJAX is a good solution here because why load all chapters at once - why not load them as and when you need them? You'd be spreading the performance burden then rather than loading them all up front when you might not need them.

Comment: good idea, i am thinking about this,

Comment: but i cannot get it work, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445425/vuejs-local-assets-path

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://webpack.github.io/docs/api-in-modules.html), you could do:

```
let myalldata = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 251; i++)
  myalldata[i] = require("assets/json/ar/ch" + i + ".json");
```

Note: for versions below v2.0.0, you will need this: 
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/json-loader

Comment: According to the `json-loader` readme, it will work for any version above of v2.0.0.

Comment: let me check this

Comment: may possible with webpack1, im using the latest version 3

Answer (score 0):

if you export them all from the same module you could do something like this:

// exports all from the same module - exportCh.js

```
export ch1 from './path/ch1'
export ch2 from './path/ch2'
/// etc
```

Then import them:

This is assuming you're able to use ES8.

```
import * as myDataSets from './exportCh'
const myalldata = Object.values(myDataSets)
```

If you can support up to ES6:

```
import * as myDataSets from './exportCh'
const myalldata = Object.keys(myDataSets).reduce((a, d) => a.concat(myDataSets[d]), [])
```

Comment: This solution involves multiple files, but if done correctly, will compile JSON files into the webpack bundle. I think this answer is better if you don't mind to have multiple files.

Comment: The question involves multiple files.

Comment: export ch1 from './path/ch1' is this not wrong, im getting error, expected {

Comment: @rashidnk - is the './path/ch1' export that file's default? if not you'll need to do something like `export * as ch1 from './path/ch1'`.

Otherwise it may be how you have your transpiler configured. What presets are you using to transpile?