# VueJs local assets path

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, quasar

I'm working on a Vuejs App. based on Quasar Framework , in  src/components/Hello.vue
there i have a function to load json file

```
axios.get('../assets/json/ar/myfile.json')
    .then(response => {
      // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    })
```

it returns error, `GET http://localhost:8080/assets/json/ar/ch78.json 404 (Not Found)`

so my question is how to get the file from src/assets folder ?
`axios.get('../assets/json/ar/myfile.json')` this line need to be corrected

Comment: I expect your src directory isn't directly available via a call to your web server. What build tool do you use for Vue?

Comment: You can use `import` for static assets.

Comment: see why im not using import here ..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46430911/simplest-method-for-copying-all-objects-into-array?noredirect=1#comment79819723_46430911

Answer (score 9):

**If the data is static** (as in this case) you could import it this way:

```
import myFile from './json/ar/myfile.json'
console.log(myFile.someProp); // will work
```

As I know Quasar Framework has configured `json` loader

**If data is dynamic** (e.g. you don't know the file name at compile time) you should store the server domain somewhere in config and join it with you dynamic path. It may look like this:

```
import { BASE_URL } from './config'
const lang = getCurrentLang(); // this is dynamic

axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/assets/json/${lang}/myfile.json`)
     .then()
     .catch();
```

In this case `./config` may look like:

```
export const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:8080';
```